# How to create new radiobuttonlist with question on submit? c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have:

```
<div id="question">
        <div style="float: left; width: 250px;">
           <asp:Label ID="question" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
        <div>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="selectdYesNo" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="btCreate" style="margin-left: 200px; margin-top: 10px;">
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Categorize" ID="btCategorize" />
    </div>
```

how can i create new entry of radiobuttonlist with new question after submit?? im princip create new  2, 3, 4 etc.

Comment: Please re-write your question because you asked it wrong. You want to add another RadioButtonList not another Item to RadioButtonList which is what we all thought reading your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        PanelFirstQuestionBlock.Visible = true;
    }
}

protected void FirstQuestionGotAnswered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PanelFirstQuestionBlock.Visible = false;
    PanelSecondQuestionBlock.Visible = true;
}
```

here your ASP:HTML

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelFirstQuestionBlock" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <h1>My first Question</h1>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonListAnswer1" runat="server" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="FirstQuestionGotAnswered">
            <asp:ListItem>yes</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>no</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="PanelSecondQuestionBlock" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <h1>My second Question</h1>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonListAnswer2" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>yes</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>no</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: why new item will be showed without radio buttons? just a question name?

Comment: and a fisrt question will take the same name as a second new one.

Comment: New item will be showed after submit because you programatically added in in first line of my code and then databinded it so RadioButtonList could start using it. All your older items will remain as they are. If you want to re-order items you should re-bind all of them.

Comment: how can i create new entry of radiobuttonlist after submit?? What does this mean?

Comment: its fine, items are showed. but new question not. i need to create everything what i wrote in my code withou button submit.

Comment: To create new question i suggest you to create RadioButtonList for each question in HTML and then just trigger RadioButtonList.Visible = true/false; Each time you load new question.

Comment: can you please show me how (update your answer)? its really hard to me today.

Comment: ani garti gam be israel, raiti she ata mi sham. ten li bevakasha tschuva eih laasot et ze. toda ahi

Answer (score 0):

You should place third entry between:

```
<%
    if (needToShowThirdEntry) {

%>
```

and

```
<%
  }

%>
```

So, your code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="selectdYesNo" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
  <%
    if (needToShowThirdEntry) {     
  %>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Maybe" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
  <%
   }        
  %>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**UPDATE**
As you updated your question, my new answer would be:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="selectdYesNo" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>


  <%
    if (needToShowSecondList) {     
  %>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="newRBList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Maybe" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
  <%
   }        
  %>
```

But, as this is separate list, you should make normal radio button list (without if) and use `newRBList.Visible` property from code behind to hide it on first rendering (before postback)

Comment: Your item is shown if some condition (needToShowThirdEntry) is true? or simply if user is submitted page, no matter what?

Comment: I would avoid inline coding simply because needToShowThirdEntry can be too complex to write inline. I would suggest to keep all logic as intended in code files.

Comment: needToShowThirdEntry can be property/method in code file, and this if is display logic. You can access (public?) properties of page class defined in code from this if. These items could be edited from code like in other answers, but it seems that I program in MVC for too long and want to keep display logic separated :)

Comment: In Views you don't have ugly Panels, GridViews and ListViews which take great amount of content body with so you can play with inline changes. We on contrary have these ugly written controls and novice developers use many of them per page.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this `selectdYesNo.Items.Add(new ListItem("text","value"));`

Comment: you miss RadioButtonList.DataBind();